# Написать программу работы с классами

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Написать программу работы с классами

Дана задача: Написать программу работы с классами. Реализовать класс Date с конструктором, принимающим 4 целочисленные переменные (days, hours, minutes, seconds). Создать для каждой принимаемой переменной закрытые члены класса и открытые возвращающие методы. Продемонстрировать работу класса в главной функции.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _22
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Date
    {

        private int one;
        private int two;
        private int three;
        private int four;

         Date()
        {
            int days = 1, hours = 2, minutes = 3, seconds = 4;
            one = days;
            two = hours;
            three = minutes;
            four = seconds;
        }

    }
}
```

Подскажите правильно ли я реализовал класс Date с конструктором, принимающим 4 целочисленные переменные и как мне здесь использовать возвращающие методы? Еще не могу продемонстрировать работу класса в главной функции, выходит ошибка о том, что класс Date недоступен из-за его уровня защиты.?

**Upd.:**

на основании замечаний в коментариях модифицировал `Date` следующим образом

Изменил модификатор доступа у конструктора, сделав его публичным:

```
public Date(int days = 1, int hours = 2, int minutes = 3, int seconds = 4)
{
    one = days;
    two = hours;
    three = minutes;
    four = seconds;
}
```

Добавил метод `Information` который возвращает необходимые мне данные, а так же выводит их значения в `console`

Вот таким образом я работаю с созданным мной классом `Date`

```
int days, hours, minutes, seconds;
Date info = new Date();
info.Information(out days, out hours, out minutes, out seconds);

 Console.ReadLine();
```

Такое решение будет правильным?

Comment: вы **НЕ** реализовали класс  с конструктором, принимающим 4 целочисленные переменные могу вам сказать на 100%  .... а возвращающие методы - это геттеры.......а `класс Date недоступен из-за его уровня защиты` потому, что у вас конструктор приватный.

Comment: Как же тогда правильно реализовать класс с конструктором, принимающим 4 целочисленные переменные. А с get set я не работал, можете подсказать как это реализовать в моем коде?

Comment: Даже если вам напишут решение, вы не сможете его объяснить. Может лучше хоть что-то почитать, хотя бы лекции, хотя бы чужие? ИМХО разумеется.

Comment: Ответы — именно для ответов. Если хотите дополнить свой вопрос, то используйте кнопку [edit]. Пока что я ваше дополнение перенёс в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Я, конечно, сделал бы свойства вместо методов, но если следовать заданию слово в слово:

```
public class Date
{
    private int days;
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    private int seconds;

    public Date(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
        this.days = days;
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    public int GetDays() { return days; }
    public int GetHours() { return hours; }
    public int GetMinutes() { return minutes; }
    public int GetSeconds() { return seconds; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var date = new Date(30, 6, 30, 15);

        Console.WriteLine(
            "Days = {0}, Hours = {1}, Minutes = {2}, Seconds = {3}", 
            date.GetDays(), date.GetHours(),
            date.GetMinutes(), date.GetSeconds());
    }
}
```